# String Concatenation in Efficient Way

Tags: ruby

My code is here

```
a="524398447598973,12312345,1234567"
b="524398447598973,123,123456789"
c=a << b
```

and i want to

```
c="524398447598973,12312345,1234567,524398447598973,123,123456789"
```

how can i do this.Please someone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
c = a + "," + b
# or
c = a << "," << b # warning: will modify 'a'
```

Just use simple string concatenation (the `+`/`<<` operator). Note that if you use `<<`, then `a` will be modified, so the first method is probably a better idea unless you don't care about `a` any more.

---

For many strings, first put them in an array:

```
myArray = ['some string', 'another string', 'string']
```

Then use the join function:

```
myArray.join(',') # some string,another string,string
# or
myArray * ',' # same as above, * is an alias for join
```

Comment: Thanks, for the solution but if i have 100 string then what should i do.

Comment: @RavendraKumar: do the same.

Comment: @RavendraKumar put them in an array, then `yourArray.join(',')`

Answer (score 2):

<strike>In this case, interpolation is the fastest.</strike>

```
c = "#{a},#{b}"
```

- Note that if you use `<<`, then `a` will also be modified, and that defeats your purpose of having the variable `c` different from `a`. So I guess you do not want that.
- <strike>And using `+` is known to be very slow. And in many people's opinion, harder to read than interpolation.</strike>

Comment: Fastest? You sure? Do you have solid numbers to back up your words? :)

Comment: I read several times that interpolation is (mostly) done during the parsing process, and is much faster than invoking methods. `<<` comes next, `+` is very slow.

Comment: How do you think it's implemented? (hint: values are not known until runtime)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev http://midwire.github.io/blog/2011/08/25/ruby-string-modification-performance/, http://adventurouszen.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/rubys-interpolation-and-its-performance/, http://tmxcredit.com/tech-blog/ruby-string-concatenation/

Comment: + ends up creating lots of intermediary objects and << has to resize the string. #{} does neither. In a case like this the difference would be pretty minimal

Comment: Actually I just ran some benchmarks and for just doing pure string concatenation `<<` is faster by several orders than any other alternative. If you want to concatenate `x` to `y` then `y << x` beats everything else hands down. Doing `x = "#{x}#{y}"` is the slowest of all alternatives: http://pastebin.com/gZuKyKD0

Comment: @sawa No problem sawa. I think those benchmarks in the blog posts were a bit misleading. It seems it really depends on what you are doing and also how you test it. I think they didn't always test it properly.

Comment: The thing to remember is that `<<` mutates the receiver, even when it's not the final assignment. It's a subtle bug-in-waiting for the unsuspecting. Also, old/stale benchmarks are very misleading and the internet is cluttered with them. Ruby's String performance has changed since 2011, so quoting old benchmarks is risky. I should know because I do enough of 'em. :-)